# Swift 2: Changing Color in Text View Object

Tags: ios

I'm trying to apply different colours to text in a Text View object like this, but text always appears in black. Does it have something to do with the Utilities settings in Xcode?

```
func returnAPI(returnAPI: String) {
    log.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    log.text.appendContentsOf(returnAPI)
}
```

Comment: Search in google for attributed text in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func returnAPI(returnAPI: String) 
{
    log.text.appendContentsOf(returnAPI)
    log.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()   
}
```

// Try like this,  i don't know it will work.